# simplexml tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

The tag [simplexml](/questions/tagged/simplexml) is ambiguous. The description of the tag describes a feature of the PHP standard library, but a significant number of questions are about an entirely different Java-based framework (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplexml+java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplexml+android for examples).  Do we need to just tag the Java questions (which seem to be a minority) with a different tag?  Or change both?

Answer (score 2):

The Java version of this tag already exists as [simple-framework](/questions/tagged/simple-framework).

Rename tag: [simplexml](/questions/tagged/simplexml) -> **php-simplexml**

Rename tag: [simple-framework](/questions/tagged/simple-framework) -> **java-simple-framework**

Add a tag synonym: **java-simple-xml** -> java-simple-framework

Retag these questions with **java-simple-framework**:

- [[simplexml] [java] -[php]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplexml+java+-php)
- [[simplexml] [android] -[java] -[php]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplexml+android+-java+-php)